# Laravel 5.5: Convert query builder to eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5, laravel-query-builder

Is there a way to transform this query builder to eloquent?

```
$transactions = DB::table('transactions')
    ->join('accounts', 'transactions.account_id', '=', 'accounts.id')
    ->select('transactions.*', 'accounts.name as account_name')
    ->paginate(5);
```

I tried it with **One To Many**. But it need the `find()` function so it give me one account's transactions but I need to select all transactions with accounts.name

Comment: Yes. Use relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Yes I know but how? :) I tried it with **One To Many**. But it need the `find()` function. I need to select all transactions with accounts.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments, you've said you have one to many relationship defined (I assume it's Accounts has many Transactions) and you need to get all transactions with account name, so do this:

```
Transaction::with('account')->paginate(5);
```

Where `account` is relationship:

```
public function account()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Account::class);
}
```

Then you'll be able to display the data like this:

```
@foreach ($transactions as $transaction)
    {{ $transaction->id }}
    {{ $transaction->account->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thats works!
That was `{{ $transaction->account->name }}` what I'm looking for.
Thank you so much @alexey-mezenin :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use models to do that.

1. Transaction model and Account model.
2. Define their relationships
3. Create a method in the transaction model to retrieve the related account names.

   function accoutNames() { //blablabla }
4. Do the query in controller, something like that:

   Transaction->accountNames();

Comment: I got this error for `Transaction::accountNames();`

**Non-static method App\Transaction::accountNames() should not be called statically**

Comment: sorry, my mistake, the mehtod should be called on an instance, its not :: but ->

Comment: Like that? `$transactions = Transaction->accountNames();`

I got this error for that :) **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)**